# how can i parsing json data android development

Tags: android

hello how can i parse json data from url
json type like this **{"code":200,"lang":"en"}**

Please help me understand this. 
I use a class jsonparser

JSONParser.class

```
public class JSONParser {

    Context Context;
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jobj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            int code = httpresponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (code == 200) {
                HttpEntity httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
                is = httpentity.getContent();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(Context, "error ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
                try {
                    jobj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jobj;

    }

}
```

MainActivity.class

```
-package,imports-

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView uid;
    String ab;
    TextView name1;
    TextView email1;
    Button Btngetdata;
    // URL to get JSON Array
    JSONParser jsonparser = new JSONParser();
    private static String url = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/detect?key=API KEY&text=hi";// JSON
```

// from url result {"code":200,"lang":"en"}

```
                                                                                                                                                                                        // Node
                                                                                                                                                                                        // Names
    private static final String TAG_USER = "lang";

    JSONArray user = null;
    JSONObject jobj = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        new JSONParse().execute();
    }

    class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            uid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            jobj = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(url);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", jobj.toString());

            JSONArray ar = jobj.optJSONArray("lang");
            if (ar != null) {
                return ar.optString(0);
            }
            return ab;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String ab) {
            pDialog.dismiss();

            } 
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us exactly what the problem is you are having

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is working for you.There is the mistake done by you is you are getting the JSONObject in to JSONArray.

Here is the modified JSONParser Async Task Code [JSONParse](http://pastebin.com/9vyMEhUL)

Thanks